# Change all users PATH variable from a deb package

Tags: java, path, package, debian, deb

My application depends on the libjss-java package. This package installs in /usr/lib/jss on Ubuntu (My target OS), so my application, that is based on java, can't find this lib if I don't add the "/usr/lib/jss" to the user's $PATH. I going to distribute this application via a debian package, can I change the $PATH variable without the need of a logout?

The application is distributed in two ways, one is a normal desktop application. The other way is an applet in a web page. I wanted to use the debian package in the second case to force the dependencies installation on the user machine so the application works correctly. To be more specific, the DEB package for the second case of my application just force the dependencies and should configure the user's $PATH.

I can already add the jss to the $PATH via the /etc/profiles, but this works only on the user login, so after installed, my application doesn't work. If this isn't the correct way, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The simple and straightforward solution is to write a trivial wrapper shell script which creates the right environment, then calls the real thing. Put this in `/usr/bin/yourapp`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jss
exec /usr/lib/jss/yourapp.real
```

where `yourapp.real` is the actual binary. I propose to install it along with the libraries for simplicity, although the FHS might insist on something like `/usr/libexec`.

Comment: This actually solves half of my problem, my application is distributed in two ways, one a normal desktop application (the case that is solved by doing this) and the other as an applet in a web page. In the case of the applet I can't use a script, because I would have to replace the Web Browser launcher I guess, and I not sure that this is a good solution for this case. I'll edit the question to mention the applet.

Comment: I don't think you can require users to install a `.deb` package locally in order to run your web applet, unless you have a very homogenous user base, all of whom are able (`root` or `sudo` privileges, etc) and willing (or forced by policy) to install packages for you.

Comment: I thought of this solution based on the google hangout example. They use a deb package to install a plugin in your browser. So the user base shouldn't be a problem I guess, my problem is how to get to the applet with the libjss-java in the PATH. I wondering if I should talk with the package mantainer to see if this is a problem with the package, as if it's installed it should be in the applications PATH I think. What do you think?